# How can I download CSV data from variable to a csv file?

Tags: javascript, papaparse

I am using papa parse library. It helped me in converting JSON to CSV but how can I download the same data into a excel file. My data is huge

Comment: If you're searching just how to make the download this could help http://stackoverflow.com/a/3665147/4682556

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you have a CSV file which you now want to tell the browser to download?
Have you looked at https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ ?
Allows you to tell the browser to download a wide variety of files.

An example in using it:

```
var blob = new Blob(myBigCSVFile, {type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "file.csv");
```

The browser, upon reaching the `saveAs` function will download the file you specified.

Comment: Thanks! Now I am able to download file with 100MB also :)

Comment: Glad it worked for your needs! If it solved the problem, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: You can avoid using `Blob`.

`let file = new File([data], "test.csv", { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8" });
saveAs(file);`

Comment: ^ this worked for me. Server was returning csv so blob conversation wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [SheetJS/js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) library.

**Supported read formats:**
Excel 2007+ XML Formats (XLSX/XLSM),
Excel 2007+ Binary Format (XLSB),
Excel 2003-2004 XML Format (XML "SpreadsheetML"),
Excel 97-2004 (XLS BIFF8),
Excel 5.0/95 (XLS BIFF5),
OpenDocument Spreadsheet (ODS)

**Supported write formats:**
XLSX, CSV (and general DSV), JSON and JS objects (various styles)